# How can I successfully pass my LiveData from my Repository to my Compose UI using a ViewModel?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to pass live events from a Broadcast Receiver to the title of my Homepage.
I am passing a String from the Broadcast Receiver to my Repository successfully, but in the end my title is always null. What am I missing?
My Repository looks like this:

```
object Repository {
    fun getAndSendData (query: String): String{
        return query
    }
}
```

Then in my ViewModel I have:

```
private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
val repoData = _data.switchMap {
    liveData {
        emit(Repository.getAndSendData(it))
    }
}
```

And finally in my Composable I have:

```
val repoData = viewModel.repoData.observeAsState()
topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = if (repoData.value == null)"null" else repoData.value!!, style = typography.body1) },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Menu)
                    }
                }
            )
        },
```

Comment: `switchMap` is your own extension, right? what exactly happens there? Also where does `_data` postValue so that switchMap can trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can use Live Data from the compose(jetpack) because it can run from the Main thread. I used onCommit() {} with interface from the compose.

```
onCommit() {
           viewModel.testCountriesList(object : NetworkCallBack {
                override fun test(response: GeneralResponse) {
                    if(response.code == 200) {
                        counties = response.response
                        responseState.value = true
                    } else {
                        responseState.value = false
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Yes, we can, please have a look at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-and-jetpack-compose

Comment: It is updating same thread if you want hit network call it wont support.